# How to store Avro format in HDFS using PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, avro

After processing input data, I've a JAVA object. I've created avro schema for storing the object in avro file. I'm stuck at writing the object using schema into HDFS. Can anyone walk me through the process of writing the object using PIG script & corresponding UDF?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using an UDF if you use Java.

So you have just to return the result of your UDF as a pig Tuple.

Then you get a relation with your data ready to store.

Finally You can use the STORE command using AvroStorage.

Comment: Any way to convert JAVA object to pig tuple? Also, can you share the syntax for storing the tuple using a avro schema file?  I've been looking for the correct syntax to use avrostorage with schema file, but couldn't find it :|

Comment: I'm not able to convert JAVA object to tuple, as JAVA object it quite complex. It involves `list`, `map`, user defined object (derived from other class) and pig doesn't support user defined classes :|

Comment: Of course you can, set your list as a tuple, your map as a pig map ... and you store all of your structure in your final tuple (ie return by your udf)

Comment: What about user defined classes, structs?